# Rails 3: Model.all => NoMethodError: undefined method 'accept' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to build a Rails app around a pre-existing MySQL database. I created the rails project, set up the database.yml file properly and created one model, User, to correspond to my users table in the db. When I run the rails console to test it out however, this is what I get:

```
 > User.all
(32.4ms)  SHOW TABLES
(34.9ms)  describe `users`
NoMethodError: undefined method `accept' for nil:NilClass
from /home/richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:7:in `to_sql'
from /home/richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:16:in `select_all'
from /home/richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:63:in `select_all'
from /home/richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:38:in `block in find_by_sql'
from /home/richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/explain.rb:40:in `logging_query_plan'
from /home/richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:37:in `find_by_sql'
from /home/richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:170:in `exec_queries'
from /home/richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:159:in `block in to_a'
from /home/richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/explain.rb:33:in `logging_query_plan'
from /home/richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:158:in `to_a'
from /home/richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:159:in `all'
from /home/richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:5:in `all'
from (irb):1
from /home/richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /home/richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /home/richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'1.9.3-p0 :002 > ^C
```

Any idea why this might be? I'm following the rails convention as far as I'm aware: I made a User model to correspond with a table called users already in the db, whose primary key is an integer field called id.

Comment: Have you some column named `visitor` ?

Comment: because it's a variable call `visitor` is nil in stacktrace. So can be the problem

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but where are you seeing the variable visitor in the stack trace?

Comment: here : https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb#L7

Comment: isn't visitor supposed to be the database-adapter in this case?

Comment: what kind of database(adapter) are you using? how is your database.yml?

Comment: And which gem you use to connect to mysql ?

Answer (score 4):

Just had the same issue. Narrowed it to being a MySQL related issue since it was happening only in staging environment (MySQL) and not in the developpment one (sqlite3). Fixed it by upgrading the `mysql2` from version 0.2.7 to 0.3.11.

Comment: This worked for me. Edited Gemfile to remove the version '< 0.3'. Then called `bundle update mysql2` and recreated the database with `rake db:drop` followed by `rake --trace db:setup`.

Comment: I'm using 0.3.11 in a non-Rails app and am still having this issue.

Comment: @BenHamill, I am also having this problem with 0.3.11, non-Rails.  Solved it by removing activerecord-mysql2-adapter from my gemspec.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem with MySQL after upgrading to rails 3.2.2.

This is what I did to fix it.

```
rvm gem install mysql2
In GemFile remove old MySQL gem and add - gem ‘mysql2' 
bundle install
bundle update activerecord-mysql2-adapter
bundle update mysql2
```

then restart your rails server.