# Undefined method 'accept' for nil:NilClass after upgrading to Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mysql-5.1

I just upgraded my Rails application from Rails 2.3.8 to Rails 3.2.7 and I've run across a problem with Activerecord.

If I try to access my database with Activerecord at all(Ex: Employee.last), I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `accept' for nil:NilClass
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:7:in `to_sql'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:18:in `select_all'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:63:in `select_all'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/querying.rb:38:in `find_by_sql'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/explain.rb:40:in `logging_query_plan'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/querying.rb:37:in `find_by_sql'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/relation.rb:171:in `exec_queries'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/relation.rb:160:in `to_a'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/explain.rb:33:in `logging_query_plan'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/relation.rb:159:in `to_a'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:378:in `find_first'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:122:in `first'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:336:in `find_one'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:312:in `find_with_ids'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:107:in `find'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/querying.rb:5:in `__send__'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/querying.rb:5:in `find'
```

I am using Rails 3.2.7 with Ruby 1.8.7.  I was previously using the mysql 2.7 version but was faced with errors when upgrading, so I am now using mysql2 (0.311) as well as  activerecord-myql2-adapter (0.0.3).

The problem seems similar to this:

[Rails 3: Model.all => NoMethodError: undefined method 'accept' for nil:NilClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296444/rails-3-model-all-nomethoderror-undefined-method-accept-for-nilnilclass)

But I tried all the solutions presented there and none of them worked.

EDIT:
If I take out the 'activerecord-mysql2-adapter' gem, I get the following error instead.

```
Address Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `addresses`.* FROM `addresses` LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `generated_methods?' for #<Class:0x7f10733eb2e8>
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:50:in `method_missing'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/markos_validates_timeliness-2.3.2.2/lib/validates_timeliness/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:46:in `define_attribute_methods'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:168:in `respond_to?'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:398:in `__run_callback'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_find_callbacks'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `send'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/base.rb:523:in `init_with'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:68:in `instantiate'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/querying.rb:38:in `find_by_sql'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/querying.rb:38:in `collect!'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/querying.rb:38:in `find_by_sql'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/explain.rb:40:in `logging_query_plan'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/querying.rb:37:in `find_by_sql'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/relation.rb:171:in `exec_queries'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/relation.rb:160:in `to_a'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/explain.rb:33:in `logging_query_plan'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/relation.rb:159:in `to_a'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:378:in `find_first'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:122:in `first'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/querying.rb:5:in `__send__'
from /home/aneyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@rails3/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/querying.rb:5:in `first'
```

Comment: What patch number are you at? Ruby 1.8.7p248 and 249 are not compatible with rails.

Comment: p370.  I'm doing this on a fresh RVM and 1.8.7 install.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured it out. Turns out a custom gem someone made a long time ago caused some errors.  Removing that gem fixed it.

For those who have a similar problem, ensure you remove the 'activerecord-mysql2-adapter' gem.  That was what caused the initial problem.

Answer (score 5):

i changed 'activerecord-mysql2-adapter' to 'mysql2' in the Gemfile, then it worked